# get URL of request sender

Tags: web-applications, servlets, request

My application is deployed as JavaScript working on some page and web application on tomcat somewhere else.

What I try to do now is find a way to determine if request was sent from given web page or was it sent from somewhere else (eg. from localhost - in this case I can not trush sent data).

When I tried to do that in my servlet - in doPost() - I was getting that servlet, as request sender `url = http://localhost:8084/app/servlet` as a result of:

```
    String domain = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString()).toString(); 
    System.out.println("url = " + domain);
```

What do I need to do, to get URL of page from which my script sent me data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is available in the [HTTP `referer` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) (yes, with the misspelling):

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
// ...
```

Please note that this is fully client-controlled -as everything else in a HTTP request. The client is able to change/spoof it. You should for sure not use it for sensitive business actions. Use it at highest for statistics or informal banners like *"Hey, welcome visitor from Google! Your search keywords are highlighted here:"* or like.

If I am not wrong, I think you're trying to reinvent Google Analytics. You may find this useful as well then: [what's the proper way to write a js that will be included in other websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068472/whats-the-proper-way-to-write-a-js-that-will-be-included-in-other-websites/6073240#6073240)

Comment: In my case this String is null. (I've tested it before opening my topic, because it was one of SO solutions.) Is it because it test it localy (I'm working on saved copy of actual page)? Does this hange anything? Or does my script need to somehow fill that header attribute?

Comment: Then the request made by your JS simply didn't include it in the request header. This totally depends on the way how you've sent the requst and on the client used. Most reliable would be to just pass it as parameter. See also the link.

Comment: So if I'm getting you right, this can simply be replaced by anyone by editing JS?

Comment: Yes. As I said, the HTTP request is 100% controlled by the client. Never trust user input :)

Comment: So is there any other way to do that?